# Regex: Get text between specific Uppercase letters

Tags: regex

I am having an issue with the following string.

```
PG CJ McCollum C James Ennis I UTIL Jonas Valanciunas IV PF Robert Covington G James Ennis II SG RJ Barrett F James Ennis III SF Royce O'Neale
```

What I have is `(?<![A-Z] )\b([A-Z]+)`. This however uses the `III` as a header. Also, `II` and `I` show up as well. I want to specifically search for `PG, C, UTIL, PF, G, SG, F, SF` and take the text in between.

Output:

```
CJ McCollum, James Ennis I, Jonas Valanciunas IV, Robert Covington, James Ennis II, RJ Barrett, James Ennis III, Royce O'Neale.
```

Commas were only added to seperate.

Comment: What language are you using? You can make a regexp that matches any of the words `PG, C, UTIL, etc.` and use that as a delimiter in a regexp split function.

Comment: @Barmar Mike is looking to essentially specify uppercase words as headers, and then store the name after each header, in a column within a pandas DF. These headers to my knowledge are random. He is looking for regex to find all headers, ignoring `I` `III` and `II` to utilising in the script found: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518454/using-defined-strings-for-regex-searching-with-python/60536297#60536297)

Comment: Thank you PacketLoss, I have since found `IV` as an issue as well.

Comment: This is the same as that earlier question. If he's having a problem with the solution there, he shouldn't post a new question.

Comment: You can make a regexp that matches any word that's all uppercase, but use negative lookahead to filter out `I+V?`

Comment: That is a different format which works for that format. My question is if I can create a list of strings to search for and return the text inbetween.

Comment: No, that was my question. I am simply looking how to structure the search. That is a separate question.